# Remove user push notifications iOS on Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push

How would you remove a user from receiving push notifications using parse? For example, if a user goes to his settings (within the app) and decides to turn-off push notifications...

I thought removing their "global" channel would do the trick, but the user seems to still be getting them. And come to think of it, if that did work, they would still be able to get pushes sent to other channels that user was associated with. Anyhow, whats the solution to this?

I've tried these two approaches:

```
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ]; //enable

currentInstallation.channels = @[]; //disable
```

AND

```
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"global" forKey:@"channels"]; //enable

[currentInstallation removeObject:@"global" forKey:@"channels"]; //disable
```

I've then tried sending a Push through Parses Web UI for both "everyone" and only those matching the "global" channel. No luck, the user still received it.

I pretty much followed Parse iOS Push setup tutorial. This is how my implementaion looks:

```
-(void)displayPushAuthRequest{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if([app respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)] && [app respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]){
        //ios 8
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    {
        //ios 7
        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];

    }

}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Save the settings locally (first time)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"didRegisterForRemoteNotifications"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}
```

Comment: How are you subscribing users to push notifications in didRegister? Additionally, theres something fundamentally wrong if your setting a specific channel  in the console but it still sends to them, thats a fundamental error somewhere.  Additionally, are you saving the `removeObject: forKey:`? it's not in your example so I had to ask

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by following approach

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation  currentInstallation];
currentInstallation.channels = [NSArray array];
[currentInstallation saveEventually];
```

Comment: doesn't work..I've edit my original post to show what i've tried thus far

Answer (score 0):

How am doing with pasrse is,
app is appdelegate object, uuidDT is device token stored in string formate in app delegate method.

`-(IBAction)notificationTapped:(UISwitch*)sender;`

```
 {

PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

if (sender.isOn)
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceToken:app.uuidDT];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
    }
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceToken:@""];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

}
```

how you will convert device token to string is below enter this code in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in appdelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    self.uuidDT=deviceTokenString;

    [currentInstallation setDeviceToken:uuidDT];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];



}
```

and its working fine.. may this is not correct way. but any way its working.....